# VB Studio IndexOf() function not working on some strings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have an array `Aircraft_Key` of strings that includes this line:
`DraganFlyer X4–ES`
And `Named_AC(intI)` contains the same string, `DraganFlyer X4–ES`.

My code is:

```
intJ = Array.IndexOf(Aircraft_Key, Named_AC(intI))
```

But any line with a dash character (Ascii 45) in the string returns a -1.  Everything else works just fine, only a dash fails the IndexOf() function.

Any ideas?

Comment: You say they contain the same string, are you absolutely sure? If you check the length of each, are they equal? If you step thru each character of each string checking its ascii value, are they equal?

Comment: Sounds like you use a different dash character in the two strings.

Comment: That was it.  I don't know how it got into the data, but the "bad" hyphen was ASCII 150.  
Many thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is one as you are expecting, but it works fine for me.

```
 Dim strValue() As String = {"DraganFlyer X4ES", "DraganFlyer X4–ES"}
 Dim strNamed() As String = {"DraganFlyer X4ES", "DraganFlyer X4–ES"}
 Dim intValue As Integer = Array.IndexOf(strValue, strNamed(1))
 Console.WriteLine(intValue)
```

Comment: may be you can check the **Named_AC(intI)** passing the correct string value or not.